# Is Douglas Hofstadter's version of Godel's proof utter nonsense?

Tags: number-theory, logic, incompleteness

Is Douglas Hofstadter's version of Godel's proof, which he offers in his book Godel, Escher, Bach, utter nonsense? Hofstadter goes to great length to disguise the fact that there are two distinct variables designated as **a'**. One of the variables designated as **a'** is the arithmoquinification of equation u, and the arithmoquinification of equation u does produce G (Godel's equation). But, the variable **a'** that is within G (Godel's equation) is definitely not the same variable **a'** that is equivalent to G (Godel's equation).

Comment: As far as I can remember, the proof given in the book is fairly solid, but it was a long time ago I read that book...

Comment: Well, per arithmoquinification, it is, IIRC

Comment: Is this a rant or a question? If it is a question, it would help to provide some more context, ideally so that one could answer the question without having the book on hand. If it is a rant, it belongs on a blog or a message board rather than a question-and-answer site.

Comment: Once I had solved tha "**b** is a power of $10$" problem, I was able to produce an explicit Gödel-like statment (though the fun part was rather tp write a program that helped expnd high-level predicates). So I'm prettty sure the book conveys the idea good enough, even if ther should be minor errors (which I do not remember to even have suspected)

Comment: It would be better to quote the specific formulae, because I have just consulted my copy of GEB and can't quite identify what you are getting at.

Comment: Here is a book which, for all its quirkiness and digressions, has been regarded by logicians as fine as far as the technical Gödelian details are concerned. Which is really more likely, do you think? That in a crucial way, it involves "utter nonsense", that no one else has spotted for 35 years? Or that you've misunderstood something?

Answer (score 6):

See page 447 (Basic Books ed, 1979) : $u$ is **not** an equation; it is a number. It is the G-number of the formula called *G's uncle* (bottom page 446).

In formula *G's uncle* there is only one free variable : **a''**.

The "trick" is to substitute the *numeral* $\overline u$ [i.e.$S(S( ...S(0)...))$, where the symbol $S$ for the "successor" function is repeated $u$-times], corresponding to the above G-number $u$, into the formula *G's uncle* in place of the **only** available "slot", i.e.in place of the free variable **a''**.

The result is a *sentence* (i.e.a closed formula : a formula without free variables) called $G$.